# My Xcode project can't find standard files

Tags: xcode, macos, ios

I have two targets -- an iOS target and a macOS target.  On the iOS target, it first fails to find the file called for by the line

```
#include "i386/types.h"
```

in the file types.h.  On the macOS target, it fails to find almost all of the headers imported by AppKit.h -- starting with the line

```
#import <AppKit/AppKitDefines.h>
```

Interestingly, it did find Foundation.h.

What went wrong, and how can I fix it?

EDIT: I know the files are present on my machine, because other projects find them no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i386 doen't make any sense on IOS so likely some settings have been messed up by having both types of targets...

So start a new project, add only the targets and see if that works out?

Comment: Ugh . . . I could do that, but I'm hoping for something less painful.  There are a lot of settings in there.